# RESTful HATEOAS Client Url

Tags: rest, hateoas

I'm reasonably sure I understand the server-side of HATEOAS design - returning state URL's in the response - but I'm slightly confused about how to design a client to accept these.

For instance, we access a resource at //somehost.com/resource/1 - this provides us with the resource data and links.  We'll assume POST to //somehost.com/resource is returned, indicating a 'new' action.  Now I understand posting some data to that url creates a new resource, and provides a response, but where does the form to post that data reside? I've seen implementations where //somehost.com/resource/1/new provides a form which POSTS to /resource, but that URL itself contains a verb, and seems to violate REST.

I think my confusion lies in that I'm implementing a RESTful API and a client to consume it, within the same application.

Is there some sort of best-practice for this sort of thing?

Comment: You are asking about the schema. Some APIs and clients utilize it, but some are more tightly coupled and just base eg. on the documentation (and not on the resource representation). Also make sure schema is universal between what "update" calls use and what is expected by "create" calls (I have seen approach where these two differ completely, which in my opinion is just bad practice, as it introduces a bit of inconsistency).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I've seen implementations where //somehost.com/resource/1/new provides a form which POSTS to /resource, but that URL itself contains a verb, and seems to violate REST.

This is incorrect. A URI *containing* a verb does not, in itself, violate any REST constraint. It is only when that URI **represents an action** that this becomes a violation. If you can perform a GET request on the URL and receive some meaningful resource (such as a "create new resource" form), then that is perfectly RESTful, **and good practice.**

My own API is exactly as you describe: `/{collection}/new` returns a form. `/new` is just shorthand for a hypothetical `/new-resource-creation-form` and still represents a noun, and only supports GET requests (HEAD, OPTIONS and TRACE not withstanding).
What HATEOAS prohibits is the user agent being required to know, that in order to create a new resource, it must add `/new` to the name of the collection.

Basically, if you implement your API as (X)HTML, and can [surf it in a browser](http://vimeo.com/20781278) and perform all actions (AJAX may be required for non-POST form submissions until HTML and browsers catch up with HTTP), then it complies with the hypermedia constraint of REST.

**EDIT** promoted from comments:

As long as the response negates any need for *a priori* knowledge, it conforms to the hypermedia constraint. If the client claims to understand HTML, and you send back a response containing a link to an external stylesheet or javascript (no matter where that is hosted) which the client needs to be able to render the page correctly, then it is reasonable to say that the constraint is met. The client should know how to handle all media types it claims to support. A normal human web browser is the perfect example of a client with no out-of-band knowledge about any one HTTP service (web site).

Just to say it explicitly, a web site is a kind of HTTP service. Web browsers do not treat different web sites differently. In order to search for products on Amazon, you load the Amazon service endpoint at `http://amazon.com/` and follow links or fill out forms provided in that response. In order to search for products on eBay, you load the eBay service endpoint at `http://ebay.com/` and do the same.
Browsers don't know in advance that for searching eBay you must do *this*, but for searching Amazon you have to do *that*. Browsers are ignorant. Clients for other HTTP services should be ignorant too.

Comment: Thank you Nicholas, this was exactly the answer I was looking for.

Comment: Nicholas, would implementing the API with HTML as the default content type for responses preclude the logical separation of a the client from the API?

For example, how would HATEOAS work when the layout of client HTML screens was sourced from a domain such as:

    example.com/*

but the data that was displayed in that screen was sourced from

    api.example.com/*

Is this type of setup feasible?

Comment: @Mackers As long as the response negates any need for a priori knowledge, it conforms to the hypermedia constraint. If the client claims to understand HTML, and you send back a response containing a link to an external stylesheet or javascript (no matter where that is hosted) which the client needs to be able to render the page correctly, then it is reasonable to say that the constraint is met. The client should know how to handle all media types it claims to support. A normal human web browser is the perfect example of a client with no out-of-band knowledge about a HTTP service (web site).

Comment: @Mackers Just to say it explicitly, a web site is a kind of HTTP service. Web browsers do not treat different web sites differently. In order to search for products on Amazon, you load the Amazon service endpoint at `http://amazon.com/` and follow links or fill out forms provided in that response. In order to search for products on eBay, you load the eBay service endpoint at `http://ebay.com/` and do the same. Browsers don't know in advance that for searching eBay you must do *this*, but for searching Amazon you have to do *that*. Browsers are dumb. Clients for other services should be too.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you *could* provide a URI that returns a form for resource creation.  Conceivably the form could be used for dynamic discovery of the elements needed to construct a new resource (but you'd want to decide how practical that would really be in a machine-to-machine environment).

Unless there is a **requirement** that somehow the API has an exact browser-surfable equivalent, the documentation of the media type will describe what elements are needed.

Remember that documentation of media types and the allowed HTTP verbs for a resource is not contrary to RESTful principles.  Look at the [SunCloud API](http://kenai.com/projects/suncloudapis/pages/CloudAPISpecificationResourceModels#Cloud_%5Bapplication/vnd.com.sun.cloud.Cloud+json%5D) for an example.

Indeed, according to your example, POST'ing to

> //somehost.com/resource

to create a new resource is more standard than first returning a form

> //somehost.com/resource/1/new

and THEN POST'ing to

> //somehost.com/resource

anyway.